# scala filter on Stream produces wrong result

Tags: scala

I'm learning scala and enjoying it, it's a very powerful language. I wrote this program to solve Euler #2 problem, from project euler. It's to find the sum of even fibonacci numbers < 4 million (called it max#).

First I used takeWhile, then filter:

```
fib().takeWhile(_ < n).filter(_ % 2 == 0).sum
```

then decided to change the order and use filter before takeWhile:

```
fib().filter(_ % 2 == 0).takeWhile(_ < n).sum
```

I did this to check if there is a difference in performance when increasing max#. The result was exact, as expected and the performance was almost identical, until I used this input number (4000000000000001237) and got 2 different results. The results are:

```
 $ scala com.ms.E2_1 4000000000000001237

   takeWhile 1st    => 3770056902373173214
   filter 1st   => -8573983172444283806
```

Can someone please explain why I get this error when I use filter before takeWhile? Thank you.

```
object E2_1 {

 def fib(a: Long = 0, b: Long = 1): Stream[Long] = {
  a #:: fib(b, a + b)
 }

 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   if (args.length == 1) { 
     val n = args(0).toLong     
     println("takeWhile 1st \t=> " + fib().takeWhile(_ < n).filter(_ % 2 == 0).sum)     
     println("filter 1st \t=> " + fib().filter(_ % 2 == 0).takeWhile(_ < n).sum)
  } else {
    println("missing args")
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're just getting an overflow. Mathematically, your `fib` might be monotonically increasing, but in practice you're using two's complement `Long`s and they will flip sign once they get large enough. Or if not the stream values themselves, then their sum.

Comment: thank you copumpkin, but why does it overflow when using filter before takeWhile and not the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the overflow affects behaviour differently depending on the order of the functions is this:

```
scala> fib().takeWhile(_ > -1).toList.reverse.take(2)
res0: List[Long] = List(7540113804746346429, 4660046610375530309)
```

i.e. the last numbers computed before overflow begins, which are greater than your target `n`, are **odd numbers**.

When you apply `takeWhile` first, the resulting stream will produce one of these numbers. The number is greater than `n`, so production stops before the results reach overflow.

When you apply `filter` first, these odd numbers are discarded. Because of overflow, the next even number produced may be negative and therefore less than `n`, so it passes the predicate in `takeWhile`! The stream will continue until the results become positive again, and a number greater than `n` is produced.

Comment: Thank you Ben, it makes sense, I tried it, as below, and fixed my filter.  
  `println(fib() filter (_ % 2 == 0) takeWhile (_ < n) takeRight (1))`
    `// Stream(-2437933049959450366)`
    `println(fib() filter (x=> x%2 == 0 && x > -1) takeWhile (_ < n) takeRight (1))`
    `// Stream(2880067194370816120)`  
Not sure about your last statement, the Stream will continue, if it does it'll be an infinit loop, but it stops.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be infinite. It probably stops because it re-overflows and becomes a positive number greater than the target `n`.